# Problem using Min(field)

Tags: mysql

```
The problem was between the keyboard and the seat folks.  
Thanks for lending your knowledge!
```

have these two queries:

```
SELECT classroomid AS crid, startdate AS msd
FROM unitTemplates where classroomid = 6
GROUP BY classroomid
```

and:

```
SELECT classroomid AS crid, Min(startdate) AS msd
FROM unitTemplates where classroomid = 6
GROUP BY classroomid
```

The second query uses the minimum function.  There is only one record in my table with a classroomid of 6.  The first query returns msd = 20100505, the second query returns msd = 0 (instead of the expected 20100505).  If I change the "Min" to "Max" it returns the highest (and only) startdate (20100505).

Why doesn't MySQL like the Min function I'm using?

---

Some additional info:
classroomid is int(11) and startdate is bigInt(20)

---

Comment: What are the types of your columns? Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE unitTemplates`. How do you know that there is only one row with classroomid = 6? Can you post the query you used to check this, and what output you get for that query?

Comment: You are absolutely right, theres a record there that I didn't see.  This is a stupid mistake on my part, sorry to be such a dolt!

Comment: It's OK - we all make silly mistakes sometimes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double-check that there is in fact only one row with `classroomid = 6`. I would suspect that there is more than one row.

Notice that your first query will always return at most one row because of the `GROUP BY`, even if there is more than one matching row in the database. The correct way to count the number of rows with `classroomid = 6` is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM unitTemplates
WHERE classroomid = 6
```

Please note in particular that there is no `GROUP BY` clause in this query.

I tried recreating the situation you described and was unable to - for me MySQL works exactly as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE unitTemplates (classroomid int(11), startdate bigInt(20));
INSERT INTO unitTemplates values (6, 20100505);

SELECT classroomid AS crid, Min(startdate) AS msd
FROM unitTemplates where classroomid = 6
GROUP BY classroomid;
```

Result:

```
6, 20100505
```

You can try running these commands yourself in a test database to convince yourself that it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the date column is formatted, but you might want to use an order by clause instead. If the date is sequential, you can use this query:

```
SELECT classroomid AS crid, startdate AS msd
FROM unitTemplates
WHERE classroomid = 6
ORDER BY startdate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This returns the single row for classroomid 6 with the max date. Change "DESC" to "ASC" and you'll get the min date.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a hack, but maybe limit the results to non-zero values?

```
WHERE startdate NOT NULL AND startdate > 0
```

Are you sure there's not a null or zeroed date in that column?